# How can I prevent u to be rendered as v when text is Latin?

Tags: libreoffice, text-formatting, opentype

## Problem and question

I am using the font EB Garamond for most of my professional work, and I am very pleased with it. There is a feature I would like the option to control, though, and I have not found any ways of doing this apart from manual editing. In the below examples Theodŏsius and Frigidus are both formatted with my character style for Latin text (which sets the language for that snippet to Latin):

[image: Figure 1: Sample text in EB Garamond, Times New Roman and Alegreya]
*Figure 1: Sample text in EB Garamond, Times New Roman and Alegreya. All examples have the names Theodŏsius and Frigidus formatted as Latin text, but the first line has the letters u reformatted to have no language setting.*

All u-s are displayed as v-s for all Latin text in roman (the style, not the font); this does not occur when the text is italic. Is there any way to forego this stylistic font setting apart from manually editing all u-s to be displayed with no language settings? I have tried accessing the stylistic sets of the font, but have found no help there. Style set 1 is petites, and I cannot see anything happening with any of the other style sets.

In summary: How can I format the character style for Latin text such that the letters u no longer are rendered as the letters v?

## Notes

1. This does not occur (not surprisingly so) when the u has a diacritic.
2. Can’t I just cease formatting the text as Latin text? There are two reasons this is undesirable: TTS rendition and accessibility, and to get rid of those pesky wavy lines. The latter also assures that I do not have any typos in the document.
3. As per the comment below, it is not an autocorrect issue; the text rendered with v is merely rendered as such; here is the actual text from the clipboard: ‘and lost to Theodŏsi**u**s himself at Frigid**u**s in 394.’
4. I am not using the deprecated EB Garamond 12 or EB Garamond 08, but the font [EB Garamond by Georg Duffner and Octavio Pardo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PDD3VT88wlBuoUxnZy6opUY0pfQ2k9wY/view?usp=sharing). This is a spinoff of the original, and fixes several issues with the original attempt, including but not limited to the rendering of ligatures and of Greek. Two months ago it was updated to v. 1.00 on [Github](https://github.com/fontalternative/eb-garamond); however, the fonts hosted there is currently corrupted.
5. I am using LibreOffice 7.1.1.2 (x64), [build fe0b08f4af1bacaf[…]](https://git.libreoffice.org/core/+log/fe0b08f4af1bacafe4c7ecc87ce55bb426164676).
6. I am assuming this to be a feature, not a bug; however, as noted above, for my purposes, this feature is a problem.

## How to reproduce

1. Set the font to EB Garamond. I have styled it as following: `EB Garamond:liga=1&calt=1&onum=1&pnum=1`. See figures 2 and 3.
2. Create a character style for foreign language; set the character style’s language to Latin. See figure 4.
3. Select the desired words and apply foreign language character style. See figures 5a and 5b (= result).
4. To remove these words’ u-s to be rendered as v-s, select the letters and set language to none (or generally any other language than Latin). See figures 6a and 6b.

Do note that it is not necessary to create a character style to achieve this; simply selecting the words and setting their language to Latin manually will achieve exactly the same result.

### Figure 2

[image: Figure 2: Plain text as in step 1.]
*Plain text as in step 1.*

### Figure 3

[image: Figure 3: Paragraph font style as in step 1.]
*Paragraph font style as in step 1. This styling can be set anywhere you change the font name; this is the font name as displayed in my paragraph style for Western fonts. If you do not have support for Asian fonts switched on, it will simply display as Font.*

### Figure 4

[image: Figure 4: Character style, language set to Latin. All other settings are default (undefined). View step 2.]
*Character style, language set to Latin. All other settings are default (undefined). View step 2.

From left to right, top to bottom:

Character style: ‘Foreign language, Latin, not italic’; [selection of tabs in character style window]; Western font; Font [font name: EB Garamond]; Style [Regular]; Size [12 pt]; Language [Latin].*

### Figures 5

#### Figure 5a

[image: Figure 5a: Words pre application of character style as per step 3.]
*Words pre application of character style as per step 3.*

#### Figure 5b

[image: Figure 5b: Character style applied.]
*Character style applied.*

### Figures 6

#### Figure 6a

[image: Figure 6a: Letters selected, manual language selection from bottom menu to be applied.]
*Letters selected, manual language selection from the right-click language menu found in the bar at the bottom of the screen. The menu for language selection reads: ‘None (do not check spelling)’.*

#### Figure 6b

[image: Figure 6b: Manual language selection applied; rendering of letters reverts back to u.]
*Manual language selection applied; rendering of letters reverts back to u.*

Comment: this may be incorporated using the dictionary and/or auto-correct behaviors. I haven't used libreoffice in this way, but I think one can examine/edit autocorrect behavior on a per-language basis in libreoffice?

Comment: Thanks for your comment; I added a note on that.

Comment: Could you post the exact steps needed to reproduce this issue? Because the u's look normal on my computer. https://i.imgur.com/83TAgun.png

Comment: Done. Some more notes added. Cheers!

Comment: @CannedMan: That's an improvement! However, I am unable to carry out the steps. First, I don't have EB Garamond as such, but only these: https://i.imgur.com/1qKbfge.png I've picked EB Garamond 12. Then I have no idea how or where to set `EB Garamond:liga=1&calt=1&onum=1&pnum=1`. As to the screenshots, I cannot read Norwegian and I wouldn't know how to do the other steps.

Comment: Translations provided; links added.

Comment: In LibreOffice (feature currently not available in OpenOffice, to the best of my knowledge), you can add OpenType features to your font definition by adding CSS selectors. For example, to add ligatures, contextual alternatives, old style numbers and proportional numbers, change the font name from plain ‘EB Garamond’ to ‘EB Garamond:liga=1&calt=1&onum=1&pnum=1’. For true superscripts (which should be added to your footnote anchor style, you would edit the font name so it reads ‘EB Garamond:sups=1’ and remove any shrinking and raising. In the latest releases, there is a selection menu for this.

Comment: @CannedMan: Oh, cool, I found out I can just type that in the box where the font name is, in the default view of the menu bar. // Okay, that took quite some time, not easy to find those actions in the menus. Especially "apply character style" took me quite a while to find (I could find anything that said "foreign language", though). Now I am trying to find "the bottom menu": I have no idea where that is. This is all very difficult without knowing the exact things to do and where to find them.

Comment: I think I did it, and it looks like this: https://i.imgur.com/ziqUdhT.png

Comment: I see from the font name that you are using the old version of EB Garamond. I am not sure whether that will reproduce the same issue. Of course, the solution provided by @user1686 solved the issue. But yes, you can type in the different characteristics as part of the font name. The bottom menu: The bar at the bottom of the screen where you get page number, word and character count, page style, current language, choose zoom level &c; bottom menu = right-click menu on current language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable the "Localized Forms" feature using `locl=0`.

Alternatively, open the font in FontForge, go to *Element → Font Info,* and in the *Lookups* section remove the unwanted GSUB lookup tables:

```
[-] 'locl' Localized Forms in Latin lookup 7
        'locl' Localized Forms in Latin lookup 7 subtable
```

Afterwards use *File → Generate Fonts* to re-export the font as "OpenType (CFF)".

Comment: I had no idea about that tag – thanks a million, it works like a charm! (That is: I used your first solution, and that did the trick.)